# Changing or setting mic source on webkitSpeechRecognition [Chrome]

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition, html5-audio, speech-to-text

I am trying to see if there is a way to input a source into the webkitSpeechRecognition. For example, user 1 sends over a live audio stream to user 2. The audio stream is given to a audio div on the user 2's side. 
Is there any way to pipe this stream as the source for the webkitspeech API?

Trying to find some docs on doing this / someone who has tried something similar.

Comment: Is there a reason user 1 cannot use the webkitSpeechRecognition? You could just send that over in addition to the live audio stream.